# how do I solve mbedtls_ssl_handshake failed error with mbedtls on stm32cubeide while connecting to AWS IOT Cloud through MQTT protocol

Tags: aws-iot, stm32f4

I am using the following development environment for connecting the stm32f429zi development board to AWS IOT Cloud using STM32CUBEIDE v1.8.0 and the secure MQTT protocol.
. Development environment
-NUCLEO-F429ZI,
-STM32CubeIDE 1.8.0,
-AWS IoT service.
Reference for the code is: https://github.com/eziya/STM32_HAL_AWS_IOT
All the certificates get parsed, but I am getting a mbedtls_ssl_handshake failed error on the SWV ITM Data console.

I am using DHCP and I am able to get the IP. Can it be the case that the network layer details are not passing on to MQTT?
I have downloaded all the generated thing certificates from AWS Cloud and put the certificates- CA3, client certificate, and private key in the code along with the endpoint and port: 8883.
I also tried using the cross-verified CA3 certificate, but still, it does not connect to the broker due to a handshake failed error. How can I prevent it?

[implementation example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWvRu.jpg)

Comment: Make sure you use this root CA: https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/AmazonRootCA1.pem

Comment: Tried using CA1 certificate as well. Still not working. Any other suggestions? Thank you in advance

Comment: do you have a correct time on your device? Make sure the time is accurate and correct.
Make sure you use the correct aws iot endpoint (xxx-ats.region.amazonaws.com)

Comment: Endpoint is correct. How to add time in mbedTLS to UTC?